# Getting a flattened JSON of arrays in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have multiple documents with the following schema

```
{
    partitionkey: 1234,
    id: 1234
},
{
    partitionkey: 4321,
    id: 4321
}
```

I'm trying to write a query that would return arrays of the ids in integers and string format.

```
{
    "id_int": [1234,4321],
    "id_str": ['1234','4321']
}
```

I used

```
SELECT VALUE id FROM c
```

to get it in the int format and used ToString() to get it in string format but I'm unable to return it in the JSON format I require that has both arrays.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this by one SQL. You can execute this SQL:`SELECT VALUE c.id FROM c`. Then transform it's result to your expected result on your client side.